# Need Assistance in selecting a service to take data from SSAS

Tags: .net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, olap-cube

I have a project coming up, and we need a service which can talk to SSAS to bring the data to the front end. After some research initially SSRS was selected , but then SSRS is limited to only IE browser.

Could any one of you please let me know which tool can be used to accomplish the same.Also, I have come across Telerik's API with connectors to SSAS , but I am not sure if that is a good choice.

Comment: What leads you to believe that SSRS only works in IE? I have worked in plenty of places that used SSRS with other browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some links that contain overviews, but probably there are many more tools:

- http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-client-tools-frontend
- http://ssas-info.com/forum/8-choosing-ssas-client-tools
- http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/category/client-tools/

And of course - depending on the type of analysis or market you are in, there are more specific solutions.